# iOS - Get current view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

In my application my initial view controller pushes a UITabBarController modally which has 4 tabs, I want to get form the AppDelegate one of the controllers in one of the tabs, but I'm not sure how to do so.

I need this to be able to handle a URL callback using

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are trying to grab one of the view controllers out of the tabbarcontroller?

```
UIViewController *myController = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```

`0` is the tab index. To use this method you'll need to know what index the tab you want is at.

Comment: Thanks Dima, it was extremely extensive to grab it considering my structure:

[[[[(UITabBarController *)[[[self window] rootViewController] modalViewController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:3] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1]